# Increase file name number by shell or linux command

Tags: shell

I have files, for example

```
- public_00000.jpg
- public_00001.jpg
- ...
- public_00535.jpg
```

But I want to make these files as

```
- public_05674.jpg
- public_05675.jpg
- ...
- public_06209.jpg
```

I mean, I want to increase the number in the filename by +5674 on the whole.

How can I do this by Shell or Command??

Thanks ahead:)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @RavinderSignh13 When I do your method, file name doesn’t change properly. I’ll analyze it and let you know. I solve my problem using second answer which use Perl. But, I really really appreciate you. I’ll let you know later why there are some problem in your Shell method. Thanks again Ravinder. Anyway voted up both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Perl `rename` like this to do an *"evaluated substitution"* - that's the `e` right at the end:

```
rename --dry-run 's|(\d+)|sprintf("%05d",$1+5674)|e' pub*jpg
```

**Sample Output**

```
'public_00000.jpg' would be renamed to 'public_05674.jpg'
'public_00001.jpg' would be renamed to 'public_05675.jpg'
```

In case you are unfamiliar with Perl, the command basically says:

```
rename "substitute|THIS|with THAT|" IN_THESE_FILENAMES
```

In your case, `THIS` is `\d+` which means *"one or more digits"* and that is enclosed within parentheses to make a *"capture group"*. That group can then be referred to in the substitution on the right side by `$1` since it is the first capture group.

The `THAT` in your case is simply a `print` statement that prints the first capture group `$1` incremented by 5674 in a field that is zero-padded to be 5 digits wide using `%05d`.

---

Using Perl `rename` has the benefits that:

- you can do a *"dry run"* to see what it would do without actually doing anything
- it will not clobber (overwrite) files without warning
- it is fast - it doesn't create a process for `sed` and another for `mv` for every single file, it just starts a single Perl interpreter and makes a library call to rename each file
- it will automagically create any intermediate directories needed, if you wish
- you can use the full power of Perl to do as much substitution or calculation as you wish

---

Note for **macOS** users... Perl is installed on **macOS** by default, so if you use **homebrew** to install your packages, you just need:

```
brew install rename
```

---

Note for Linux users... there are several `rename` packages, the one I am referring to is sometimes called `prename`, or "Perl rename". That means, if you run `file` on the `rename` command, it should say it's a Perl script like this:

```
file $(which rename)
/usr/local/bin/rename: Perl script text executable
```

Comment: This might become problematic if you have want to add the number `10` to a file `file_0001`, but you already have a file `file_0011`. A safe way would be to use `rename` twice.

Comment: @kvantour In any case, as I said in the *"benefits"* it will not overwrite the file, so it is perfectly "safe" as it is. But yes, if the OP does have files not named as the questions states, he could rename the files via some intermediate non-clashing naming scheme and make 2 passes.

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following.

```
for file in *.jpg
do
   first_filename_part="${file%_*}"
   last_filename_part="${file#*.}"
   var="${file#*_}"
   count="${var%.*}"
   ((count = count + 5674))
   printf "%s %s %s_%05d.%s\n" "mv"  $file $first_filename_part $count $last_filename_part
done
```

Above will only print the commands on screen like:

```
mv public_00000.jpg public_05674.jpg
```

---

---

Try running only 1 command First from above printed output on your terminal, once you are Happy with results try following then, since this will rename all the files.

```
for file in *.jpg
do
   first_filename_part="${file%_*}"
   last_filename_part="${file#*.}"
   var="${file#*_}"
   count="${var%.*}"
   ((count = count + 5674))
   printf "%s %s %s_%05d.%s\n" "mv"  $file $first_filename_part $count $last_filename_part | bash
done
```

---

---

From man page: I have used parameter expansion mechanism.

> ${parameter#word}
>
> ${parameter##word} Remove  matching  prefix  pattern.  The word is
>   expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the
>   pattern matches the beginning of the value of parameter, then the
>   result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the
>   shortest matching pattern (the  `#''  case)  or the  longest matching
>   pattern (the`##'' case) deleted.  If parameter is @ or *, the
>   pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parame- ter in
>   turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.  If parameter is an
>   array variable subscripted with @ or *, the pattern  removal 
>   operation  is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the
>   expansion is the resultant list.
>
> ${parameter%word}
>
> ${parameter%%word} Remove  matching suffix pattern.  The word is
>   expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the
>   pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter,
>   then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter
>   with the shortest matching pattern (the `%'' case) or the longest
>   matching pattern (the`%%'' case) deleted.  If parameter is @ or *,
>   the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter
>   in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.  If parameter is an
>   array variable subscripted with @ or *, the pattern removal operation
>   is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is
>   the resultant list.

Comment: Good answer but you can catch `count` way simplier by removing all non digits like so `count=${file//[!0-9]/}` And inc it like so `count+=5674`

Comment: @Ivan, ok I just found one edge case, let's say in case any number is coming before digit part which comes in between first and last part, then results may come false positive, please do lemme know your views on same.

Comment: Yes if file name have two(or more) digit cluster like `01_some_name_0152.jpg` this method would fail, but it this case `public_05674.jpg` it'll work fine

Comment: ++ but `var=$(echo "${file#*_}")` can be just `var="${file#*_}"`

Comment: ++ved for the concise and self-explanatory answer. If you allow me to be nickpicking, it will be more robust to rename
in the reverse (number descending) order starting with the number-largest filename considering the possible *overlap* between
the original (smaller) numbers and new (larger) numbers during the renaming process.
If the new numbers are smaller than the original numbers, the relationship is vise versa.
Of course there may be no chance to cause an overlap in this case with 5,674 distance and there is no need to modify
your answer. Just a self-talk :)

Comment: Surely you are commenting to have a dry-run in your answer,  there will be nothing to worry about my concern, of course.